# Name [ ] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc] Tomcat Issues

Tags: tomcat, database, jdbc

I just created a fresh Oracle Linux 7 VM with Tomcat 7 and Java 8_40.  I've created several servers with Apache and Tomcat before, but never connecting to databases before.  SELinux and firewalld are both off (for testing purposes.)  I can't seem to get the jdbc configured correctly.  Here's what I have:

Context.xml:

```
<ResourceLink global="jdbc/JCAppsCoreDS" name="jdbc/JCAppsCoreDS" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```

Server.xml

```
    <Resource name="jdbc/JCAppsCoreDS" auth="Container"
   type="javax.sql.DataSource"
   driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
   url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//******/PROD"
   username="******" password="*****"
   initialSize="5" maxActive="100" maxIdle="-1" maxWait="30"
   validationQuery="select 1 from dual"
   testOnBorrow="true"
   factory="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory" />
```

With the ***** being actual items of course.  When I try to go to the URL of my application I get:

Naming exception Error while connecting to the database : javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/JCAppsCoreDS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].

As far as I can tell, my config is correct, but I'm still getting errors.  Anybody have any ideas?  Also, I don't see much as far as this error goes in the logs.  Does anyone know which logs and where I need to increase the log level?  I've messed with them a bit, but haven't been able to get more info.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Did you configure the Resource reference in `web.xml`?

```
<resource-ref>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/JCAppsCoreDS</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Comment: I did not, thanks for that!  I'm still getting the same error though.  What I'm doing is moving a Weblogic application over to Tomcat.  I basically just grabbed the war file off of the Weblogic server and deployed it on my new Tomcat server.  Maybe that'll help us come up with an answer?

Thanks!

Comment: Does anyone know of any logs that could be set to show any errors for this issue?  I can't seem to find ANYTHING of any use in the logs currently.

Comment: Did you configure the database in the GlobalNamingResources?

Comment: partial solution, new errors appeared, but it looks like a step forward

Answer (score 1):

We just figured out the issue yesterday though, the applications we are trying to move from weblogic to tomcat calls the database in a way that weblogic recognizes, but tomcat does not.  We're going to edit the database call and use spring to hopefully make everything work together.  Thanks for the tips though!